# Any easy way to retarget an animation to another rig?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, retargetting

I've got a motion capture extracted from a video using [Meshcapade](https://me.meshcapade.com) (well, it's awesome!).
It gives me a basic character, rigged and animated.

Now, I want to transfer that animation to another rig.  I found a nice one on [ActorCore](https://actorcore.reallusion.com/3d-character/free).

Is there an easy way - or what's the easiest way - to transfer the animation from one rig to the other one, without it being an hassle ?

I plan to use this process quite often and I would like to build a smooth & optimized workflow for it.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Use an addon like [this one](https://github.com/Mwni/blender-animation-retargeting) or AutoRigPro. There is no retargeting built in to Blender natively.

Comment: There is also [Expy Kit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pFouaNVxcso&list=PLlYRBY5qQKSkd5E21U8TSDONzYSsRCupG&index=1) that supports Rigify. Another one is the [Rokoko add-on](https://youtu.be/5nHgYO8vzf4?feature=shared) for Blender which supports retargeting.

Comment: Exactly how much hassle is necessary depends on the similarity of the rigs involved.  Biped to insect?  Not going to happen, basically ever.  Identical bone names, axes, and rest pose?  Then it's a single reassignment of the action from one rig to the other.  There is a wide area between those two where the retargeting becomes increasingly complicated (and increasingly error-prone.)