Connect animation to model
I have an FBX file with a model and multiple FBX files with only the animation (keyframed bones).
If I play the animation, I only see the bones move but not the bones on the actual model. I was wondering how to apply the keyframes to the model.

Left is the model, right are the moving bones.

See if this helps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/315384/any-easy-way-to-retarget-an-animation-to-another-rig or search Google for animation retargeting in Blender.

Is retargeting still necessary if the animation is specifically made for this model? All the bone names match on both armatures. I assume there is a method to "apply" it?

I'm not sure since I've never had to do it myself but there should be YT videos showing you how to do it.

if the bones have the same names, it should work, could you please share your file?

If the name and orientation of the bones and the bone hierarchy match, the animations should work fine on both armatures. The animations just need to be linked/applied to the armature of the mesh object. To link an animation to an armature, select it then:

Open the Dope Sheet editor.



Switch to the Action Editor mode.



Use the action drop-down to link the action (animation).


